# Замена значения в переменной сопоставлением

Tags: python, python-3.x

С помощью API Яндекс.Погоды запросом получаю прогноз погоды, в ответ получаю JSON. Вытаскиваю значение нужного ключа, а именно `condition`. Значение ключа приходит мне на английском, а нужно отдать его на русском. В документации есть расшифровка значений:

[image: расшифровка]

Собственно сам вопрос: каким образом организовать сравнение приходящего значения с расшифровкой (есть мысль засунуть её в словарь) и последующую замену на русскоязычное значение?

Comment: Вы сами описали ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов вопрос как заменить. Читал про `replace`, но видел только примеры, где заменяют "одно" на "другое". У меня же вариантов этих "одно" и "другое" несколько

Comment: Сначала найти какое "одно", потом заменить.

Comment: в качестве и "одного" и "другого" можно использовать переменные, которые будут содержать нужный текст из словаря

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, о чём написали комментаторы. Немного не в то русло думал. Решил вопрос очень просто:
`ru_condition = en_condition.replace(en_condition, dict[en_condition])`

где `en_condition` - приходящее с сервера значение на английском, `dict` - словарь с расшифровкой значений составленный по скриншоту.

Всем спасибо

Comment: У вас выражение заменяет текст исходной строки целиком. Проще тогда `ru_condition = dict[en_condition]` написать.

Comment: @insolor резонно